# How to ensure mutual exclusion?

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, debian, lazarus, freepascal

I'm creating a multithread application and I want to protect some instructions so only one thread can execute them at a given time. But I really don't know how to realize this, so is there any function that do the mission? 
Thanks for your replies

Comment: What programming language are you using for?

Comment: I'm using Lazarus IDE, which means language is Pascal.

Comment: [Multithreaded Application Tutorial/Critical sections](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Multithreaded_Application_Tutorial#Critical_sections)